# When is the sum of distances minimal?

Tags: geometry

Given a rectangle $ABCD$ on a cell sheet.  Here $AB = 3$; $AD = 4$. Two point $M$ and $N$ are chosen inside the rectangle.  The distance from $M$ to $AB$ is equal to $1$, the distance from $M$ to $AD$ is equal to $2$. The distance from $N$ to $CD$ equals $2$; from $N$ to $AD$ equals $1$. Points $Q$, $R$, $S$, $T$ were chosen on the sides $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $AD$. At what positions of the points $P$, $Q$, $S$, $T$ is the sum $MQ + MR + MS + MT + NQ + NR + NS + NT$ minimal?

[image]

From the conditions we know that we cannon change the positions of points $ M $ and $ N $. Also I think I know a theorem that might help here.

Theorem. Given two points $ A $ and $ B $ and a line $ l $, find a point $ C $ on the line $ l $ if we know that $ AC + BC $ is minimum. (In the case when the points lie on different sides of the line, we must only draw a line, and if not, we have to draw a point $ D $ which is symmetrical to $ B $, and then connect $ A $ and $ D $.)

Comment: Hint: minimize each partial sum $MQ+NQ$ independently.

Comment: So I have to do MQ and NQ, MR and NR, MS and NS..., right?

Comment: Right. You can choose the $4$ points independently, since the position of $Q$ only affects $MQ+NQ\,$, and similar for the others.

Comment: There is a symmetry to the figure such that $MQ+NQ = MT + NT = MR+NR$

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are four independent sub-problems solved by finding the optimal position of $Q$, $R$, $S$ and $T$.  So consider just the $Q$ location:  Consider Fermat's principle of least time applied to light passing from a point $M$ to a mirror ($AB$) to $N$:  It does so along the shortest path... *which leads to the law of reflection*:  that the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection.  Application of this law will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there are four independent sub-problems solved by finding the optimal position of $Q$, $R$, $S$ and $T$. So consider just the $Q$ location: Consider Fermat's principle of least time applied to light passing from a point $M$ to a mirror ($AB$) to $N$: It does so along the shortest path... which leads to the law of reflection: that the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection. Application of this law will solve your problem.
[image]

If you're really sophisticated, you'll use the principle of virtual images to find the location of $Q$:  The total distance $MQ + QN$ is the same as $MQ + QN^\prime$, where $N^\prime$ is the "virtual" image of $N$ on the other side of the mirror $AB$, i.e., at location $(-2,1)$.